# C pointer to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array that is 240x320 bytes in size, and the pointer to this buffer is stored in the memory address 0xE30014. I have tried to define this as follows:

```
#define buffer (*(uint8_t (*)[240][320])0xE30014)
```

Because I wish to be able to index the array in a manner like this:

```
buffer[x][x] = some_val;
```

However, this throws the error that an array is not a legal lvalue. I was wondering what is wrong with the current define? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Declare `uint8_t **buffer; `. You can do buffer[0][0] = 0; If you know the address, make buffer = 0xE30014.

Comment: Updated post so it isn't that easy; but yes that answers the direct question, heh.

Comment: Oh :( `However, this throws the error that an array is not a legal lvalue.`: What is array here? Post the exact error print.

Comment: Changed `uint8_t` ro `char` and not getting any compiler errors for this: `#define buffer (*(char (*)[240][320])0xE30014)`

Comment: [Your macro works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/263783a0570696f4). Of course it segfaults at runtime because `0xE30014` is an invalid address, but there isn't any compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript operator `[]` can be mostly used with only arrays or pointers. But, here you are using a macro for the so called pointer which you want to use. Now, `buffer` will be directly replaced by `(*(uint8_t (*)[240][320])0xE30014)` which the compiler finds to be neither a pointer nor a declared array and hence the error.

The compiler views your expression as a typecasted constant and doesn't view it as a pointer and hence your error.

Comment: Right, so it looks like it has to be a variable rather than a macro. I guess that is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, a variable has a type associated with it, so that should be acceptable.

Comment: `(*(uint8_t (*)[240][320])0xE30014)` is an lvalue of type `uint8_t[240][320]`, an actual array. That it has been obtained by dereferencing a pointer-to-array, which itself comes from a cast, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that my acceptable answer to this solution is dereferencing the pointer and then type casting it. The extra cast is necessary because pointers to arrays and arrays are the "same" thing.

```
#define buffer (**(uint8_t(**)[240][320])0xE30014)
```